# How to search for a sequence of words in documents in Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a sequence of words in `xquery` like this (and, transaction, search, business). Now I want to search for this sequence in documents (like pdf, doc, ppt) as well as in `xml` files. If any of the words matches in any of the document then the `URI` of that document should be returned. What is most efficient way of doing this in `Marklogic` with `xquery` ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the first problem is to tokenize the words out of a user-supplied string. Here's a simple way to do that using `cts:tokenize` http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/SearchBuiltins.xml&category=SearchBuiltins&function=cts:tokenize

```
cts:tokenize('now is the time')[. instance of cts:word]
```

Once you have the words, you could use them with the `cts:word-query` constructor and `cts:search`, or you might extend the high-level search API to handle this: perhaps using `search:resolve` http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/searchapi.xml&category=Search&function=search:resolve

Naturally any binary content (pdf, doc, ppt) will need document conversion first: http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/xml/search-dev-guide/binary-document-metadata.xml